# How to kill a process in window without killing current process

Tags: python, cmd, process

Hello I just wont to kill a process without killing current process suppose that i have a python code which write a string in txt file e.g

```
import os
while True:
    with open('input.txt' , 'r') as re:
        all_data = re.read()
    if all_data == 'pause':
        os.system('kill.bat')
    else:
        print("\nContinue\n")
```

here it will read input.txt and if it is equal to pause then it will run kill.bat here i would like to restart this code for doing this i will write another script kill.bat which restart this code but the problem is it is not restarting because it was killing kill.bat file but i wont to kill only python terminal and restart it how can i do it here is kill.bat file code

```
taskkill /IM cmd.exe
python main.py
```

main.py is my python file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nice try @Pryanshu

You're doing it right. The problem with your current approach is python and the batch script will be under same process and get's killed at the same time.
So just change the approach a bit

here's the gist:

**python**

```
get current process id
while loop 
    read file
    if matches condition
        call kill.bat and pass this python process ID as separate process
```

**batch**

```
get first parameter (which is the python process to kill)
kill the process via taskkill
start the python script as seprate process
exit
```

**Helpers**

```
get current process ID     - pid = os.getpid()
pass id to batch script    - os.system("kill.bat %s" % pid)
batch script get arguments - %1
                             this %1 will contain the first argument passed. 
                             by default %* will contain all the arguments passed to the script.
python start program as 
separate process           - use subprocess python package
cmd start program as 
separate process           - use Start command
kill process via taskkill  - taskkill /F /PID <pid>
                             replace <pid> with your argument
```

I know you can handle the code part. You'll have to make use of the *Helpers* and combine them to do the task. Lemme know the output.

If you have any question do comment. I'll try to reply ASAP

Cheers

Comment: Thanks I will Try This one